# Pass credential details to open up an application javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

Scenario:
-Step 1: User adds login details in my client application A (written in angular 2).
-Step 2:From my client , I need to open up another application B(this opens up login page)
-Step 3: My application A should open up Application B . App A should use login details provided by the user to open up App B.

Issue:
I am using `window.open("Application B")`.
But I am not sure how to pass login details already available in App A to open up App B.

Please help

Comment: You cannot send data between tabs or windows. You can call an url like `example.com?user=john&password=doe` to open application B. But there will be some securities issues. Or you can set your data inside cookies. Application B will read those cookies if there are present

Comment: Is there a way javascript autofills the login details on opening App B.

Comment: If the javascript is on App B - yes

Comment: I already proposed you 2 solutions in my first comment. Try one of them then come back if you have a problem/error

Comment: Application A is written is angular2.

Comment: Application A is written is angular2. Application B is written in swing . So, option 1 to add credeantial in the url doesnt work . This is not supported by Application B. Option 2: Snce i am using window.open(), i cannot pass cookie object to it

Comment: Cookies are stored inside the browser

Comment: And Option 1 can totally work